# How to improve serialization performance of large lists of composed objects

Tags: object-oriented-design

Let's say we have the classic `Invoice` object.

This `Invoice` object has various properties, including a `Product` and `Customer` object.

The `Product` object has a minimum of 15 properties.

Now say i have a list of invoices of customers who all bought the same product. When I serialize this data to the client, the size of the data is approaching several megabytes (seen in the Chrome devtools network tab). This isn't such a big deal for my machine, but on mobile it can lead to drastically slower load times.

Each `Invoice` in this list contains the exact same `Product`, with the same 15+ properties taking up space in memory. It feels really inefficient to send this repeated data over the network. I really only need the `Product` info once, the important data is the customers and the sales figures, etc, the data that differentiates each invoice.

How can I structure my data in a way that has minimal data repetition?

EDIT: To be clear, i'm talking about the potential size of the JSON response, and how to reduce it in order to not blow up mobile devices/slower devices.

Comment: Are you able to use javascript on the client to reorder the data and put it back into its desired presentation?

Comment: I guess i could. But i would still have sent allll that data already. Maybe i can just restructure the data right before serialization. That way i can still perform business logic on simple lists, and then change it into some sort of `Map<Product, List<Invoice>>` and take out the product object from all the invoices.

Comment: if you can manipulate your data on the client you could essentially do the product<->invoice join on the client, and only send the product info once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about database normalization and denormalization.

Chances are good in your database you have separate tables for Invoices, customers, products, etc, and other tables that map elements of those all together (or some similar design). When you have your invoice table, rather than put all the customer information in a row, often you'll just have a foreign key, with a single integer or similar that matches an identifier on your customer row in the customer table. When you produce your list, you `JOIN` all that information together and report it.

When you serialize that list, the foreign key to id mapping gets lost, and the contents of each piece of `JOIN`ed information gets repeated over and over, which is the problem you're having.

So, one solution is to bring some of that joining intelligence over to the client. Send your invoices and products as separate lists, and use your client-side software to put all the pieces together, referencing keys and IDs, just like the database would.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your advice, i'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

As invoices are built, just reference the product Id as part of the invoice, not the entire product.

> invoice
>     product id=1...
>     product id=1...

Then have another section that is your product list that lists each product *once*.

- product id=1, name=Widget, next 15 properties etc....
- product id=2, name=Fidget, next 15 properties etc....

Then your client can use the reference ids to find the full product for each invoice line item.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained why this is a problem. Normally, if a Product type object is reusable, it should be reused, and the serialization framework (if any good) will recognize it is the same object, and avoid re-serializing the object.

You already know how to structure the data: reuse identical Products. Making use of a better serialization framework is a separate issue. Typically an efficient serialization framework does not try to save everything as a directed acyclic graph, but rather as a flat list of objects, with synthesized object identifiers (typically integers) used to connect objects together. Such a framework has no need to redundantly serialize the same object.

Comment: You answer **seriously confuses** the difference between what a serialization library does vs. what your data structures would do, to accomplish the OPs goal.

Comment: I meant the problem to be more in terms of the size of the json structure being sent to the client. I felt it unnecessary to have the `Product` json repeated for each invoice, as this takes up memory and may cause slow load times for mobile devices.

Comment: @whatsisname Having created several serialization systems over the past 30 years, confusion is unlikely. Preventing redundant serialization of objects in the graph is the responsibility of the serialization system. If the Products and Invoices are serialized in separate streams, it is necessary to use a different referencing mechanism; an SKU or product identifier.

Comment: @FrankHileman: Regardless how much skill or familiarity you have with serialization, you did not clearly communicate your ideas.